# Java concurrent set with timeout

Tags: java, concurrency

I need some Java collection which holds String values and has synchronized method for adding an element if it doesn't exist already (something like [addIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#addIfAbsent%28E%29) is for ArrayList). Collection would be under heavy-traffic. Also I would like to have some timeout mechanism after which entry in a collection expires. Timeout should be around 5 seconds.

Any suggestions for elegant solution? Choice of collection without timeout mechanism would be helpful too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting time-out as a time value after which an item inserted into the collection will be removed, maybe the [Guava Cache implementation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) is suited to your needs? It doesn't directly expose a `putIfAbsent` method but you can use the `CacheLoader` or provide a `Callable` to generate a value if needed.

```
String value = cache.get("key", new Callable<String>() { ... });
```

The callable would be called if `cache` did not contain a value for the given `key`.

Comment: Guava Cache looks like something that would do the trick for me. One thing I didn't mention in my question is that I need to know if the key was already present in cache when calling `cache.get(...)`. To be precise I need atomic put-if-absent with return info about the prior presence of the key in cache. The only solution I was able to find is to use cache as a map:
`value = cache.asMap().putIfAbsent(key, value)`
In that way I'm loosing Guava self loading operations, but I'm using their timeout mechanism. What do you think about that?

Comment: @njosa: If you really need the information "I inserted it but it was absent before" then I guess you will have no other choice. If you only want to make sure that the value is indeed in the map when requested later, the `cache.get(String, Callable)` method is better. The `Callable` will be called and generates the value when requested and absent. So it is transparent for the caller. If you just need the information whether an item is currently present `getIfPresent()` might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to implement some form of caching mechanism? If so, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. You can use some cache implementation, like EhCache.

Please, take a look at this thread: [similar question about collections with timeout (caches)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352864/how-can-i-run-a-background-thread-that-cleans-up-some-elements-in-list-regularly)

Comment: Thank you for you help, that thread really helped me understand what I really need here.